# How can I do this with a regex pattern?

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, textmate

I am writing a custom `TextMate / Sublime Text 2` bundle for 6502 Assembly language.

Anyway, I want to be able to identify constants, variables, etc.

I have this for `HEX` numbers:

```
<dict>
    <key>match</key>
    <string>#?\#[0-9a-fA-F]+</string>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>constant.numeric.decimal</string>
</dict>
```

But it doesn't really work for the following:

```
#14              // works
#$2F             // works
#coolVariable    // doesn't work.  The "#c" is caught and colored but the rest is not.
                 //                In this case, I DON'T want any of it to be colored.
```

Like the code says, it shouldn't color the `#coolVariable` but it's grabbing the `#c` piece of it.

I want to color variables like that separately.  What would be the regex to differentiate between the two patterns?

So that:

```
#c0      //  Caught by one pattern  (values in decimal or hexadecimal or binary)
#%10101  //  Caught by one pattern  (values in decimal or hexadecimal or binary)
#c0BLAH  // Caught by another pattern
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\#[0-9a-fA-F]+\b
```

To mark that the word must end before any other characters are used.

Answer (score 0):

use \b for word boundry

so put `\b#?\#[0-9a-fA-F]+\b`